# Laravel 5.5.24 not showing css, javascripts and images

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I have a problem with a Laravel installed in a AWS Ubuntu machine. I was working on my computer via localhost (using the server via PHP in the public folder) I could see everything on the page. The bootstrap works perfect. All the CSS libraries, images and js are called and the page works like a charm.

When I deployed to my repository and my server I was surprised to see that the styles were not working.
First I thought maybe was the reading permission in the public folder, so I give it reading permission, this didn't work. After trying I gave all the Laravel folder 777 permission (I know that it is not ideal, but I'm kinda of desperate).

I was searching for another way to call the libraries. In the beginning I had this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/custom.css">
```

After some research, in some pages mentioned that it will be better if I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}">
```

This didn't work. So I have tried this other options:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/somestylesheet.css') }}" />
{ HTML::style('css/css.css'); }}
```

Both of them don't work either. I have tried this with all the js and images also but none of the are loading.

I have a similar page in another Instance in a AWS with Ubuntu and Apache, same configuration and it works.

The weird thing is that when I installed the Laravel in the server it displayed the home page of Laravel, but after I made the changes it stopped working

I'm looking in the developer tools to see what the problem is and I'm getting this.

[image]

It is like the Laravel its not letting the libraries to be accessed, but I have no idea how to make it work.

If you gals and guys need any extra information, I will be glad to let you know.

Comment: Make sure that the assets are actually on the server. From check your website and going to the URL where they're supposed to be, I got 404.

Comment: Yep all the files I'm calling are in the server in the public folder. But I cannot access them via my web site URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I find the error. It was the apache in the VirtualHost.

When declaring the DocumentRoot I made it pointing to the /public/index.php.
It has to be declared just in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can't find your style files (404's in your screenshot of the network log). Are you sure they are present in the public directory? If you can't access them directly (e.g. yoururl.com/css/style.css). It's likely that they aren't present. Maybe you need to run npm run prod?